# parcelable encountered ioexception writing serializable object.........?

Tags: android, serializable

The code

```
SngList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView a, View v, int position, long id) {


        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NowPlaying.class);
        intent.putExtra("Data1",Songinfo);
        intent.putExtra("Data2",position);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

code in the receiving class

```
Intent i = getIntent();
ArrayList<SongDetails> Songinfo2 = (ArrayList<SongDetails>)i.getSerializableExtra("Data1"); 
position=i.getIntExtra("Data2", 1);
```

code for songDetials

```
package sourcecode.jazzplayer;

import java.io.Serializable;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class SongDetails implements Serializable{
    Bitmap icon ;
    String song;
    String Artist; 
    String Album;
    String Path;
   int icLauncher;

    public String getSong() {
        return song;
    }

    public void setSong(String song) {
        this.song = song;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return Artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String Artist) {
        this.Artist = Artist;
    }

    public Bitmap getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.icon = bitmap;
    }

    public String getPath2() {
        return Path;
    }

    public void setPath2(String Path) {
        this.Path = Path;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {
        return Album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String Album) {
        this.Album = Album;
    }

    public void setIcon(int icLauncher) {
        this.icLauncher = icLauncher;
    }
}
```

the whole code:

```
public class FragmentSongs extends  Fragment implements Serializable {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_song, container, false);
        ListView SngList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.SongList);
        registerForContextMenu(SngList);
        File f=new File("/system/");
        //File f=new File("/sdcard/Music");
        int j=0;int i=0;



         final ArrayList<SongDetails> Songinfo = getSongsFromDirectory(f);

        if (Songinfo.size()>0)
        {

            for( j=0; j<Songinfo.size();j++)
            {
                for ( i=j+1 ; i<Songinfo.size(); i++)
                { 
                    SongDetails a=Songinfo.get(i);
                    SongDetails b=Songinfo.get(j);
                    if(a.getSong().toLowerCase().compareTo(b.getSong().toLowerCase())<0)
                    {   

                        Songinfo.set(i,b );
                        Songinfo.set(j,a);
                    }
                }

            }

            SngList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView a, View v, int position, long id) {


                       Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NowPlaying.class);
                       intent.putExtra("Data1",Songinfo);
                       intent.putExtra("Data2",position);
                       startActivity(intent);

                             }
                     });

           SngList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(Songinfo));
           return view;
        }
        else return null;

    }



        public ArrayList<SongDetails> getSongsFromDirectory(File f)
        {MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            ArrayList<SongDetails> songs = new ArrayList<SongDetails>();
            Bitmap bitmap2; 
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ab);

            float ht_px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            float wt_px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int) ht_px, (int) wt_px, true);



           byte[] rawArt = null;
            Bitmap art;
            BitmapFactory.Options bfo=new BitmapFactory.Options();
            if (!f.exists() || !f.isDirectory()) 

            {    
                return songs;
            }
            File[] files = f.listFiles(new Mp3Filter());
            for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) 
            { 

                if (files[i].isFile())
                { 


                 //mmr.setDataSource(files[i].getPath());
                // rawArt = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
                    SongDetails detail=new SongDetails(); 
                //if ( rawArt != null) 

                //{ 
                    //bitmap2=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawArt, 0, rawArt.length, bfo);
                    //bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, (int) ht_px, (int) wt_px, true);

                    //detail.setIcon(bitmap2);
                //}//else 
            //{     
                    detail.setIcon(bitmap2);
                //} 

                    detail.setSong(files[i].getName()); 
          // detail.setArtist(files[i].getName());
          // detail.setAlbum(files[i].getName());

             //detail.setArtist(mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST)); 

          // detail.setAlbum(mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM)); 
           detail.setPath2( files[i].getPath()) ;
           songs.add(detail); 
                }
                else if (files[i].isDirectory())
                { 
                songs.addAll(getSongsFromDirectory(files[i])); 
                } 

            }       return songs;
    }
        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
        {
                        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);      
                       info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
                       menu.add(Menu.NONE, v.getId(), 0, "Play");
                       menu.add(Menu.NONE, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");
                       menu.add(Menu.NONE, v.getId(), 0, "Queue Item");                  
               }

        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                if (item.getTitle() == "Play") {

                       }
                 else if (item.getTitle() == "Delete") {

                       }

                 else if (item.getTitle() == "Queue Item") {

                       }
                 else     {
                       return false;
                       }
               return true;
               }}


        class Mp3Filter implements FileFilter
        {
            public boolean accept(File file)
            {
            return (file.isDirectory()||file.getName().endsWith(".apk")|| file.getName().endsWith(".Mp3"));
            }
        }
```

The Log

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing
>   serializable object (name = sourcecode.jazzplayer.SongDetails)

Comment: The problem is caused by: `java.io.NotSerializableException:` Is your class `Songinfo2` serializable?

Comment: well songinfo is an object of songdetails class and i have implemented serializable on it

Comment: can you post your class SongInfo?

Comment: i am sorry for using capital "S" in songinfo...as i said.its not a class..if you meant SongDetails...i have updated my question and provided you with the code

Comment: please post your code properly. then only we can find what is your problem!!!

Comment: final ArrayList<SongDetails> Songinfo = getSongsFromDirectory(f);

Comment: please post your activity fully.

Comment: @Nirmal yeah sorry but had Songinfo been a string i would not have used Serializable.....because Serializable is used for objects of classes that you have created and not inbuilt classes(or data type its commonly said)

Comment: @Nirmal posted the whole code

Comment: Well yes you may say........i am able to generate the list in a custom adapter but the problem arises when i click on it..i want to play the song in another activity.....and i am unable to pass Songinfo(the object)....i am able to pass any other object of inbuilt data types..like int and string and all....but not the object of this class.....

Comment: @Nirmal ..got any idea what i should do

Comment: @mirco.widmer got any idea what i should do ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok i implemented part of it for you. You have to add all the other properties of your SongDetails class:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SongDetails Songinfo1 = new SongDetails();
    Songinfo1.setSong("song1");

    SongDetails Songinfo2 = new SongDetails();
    Songinfo2.setSong("song2");

    ArrayList<SongDetails> list = new ArrayList<SongDetails>();
    list.add(Songinfo1);
    list.add(Songinfo2);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Data1", list);
    intent.putExtra("Data2", 1);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

In the activity in which you are retrieving the songs, use this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_asdf);

    ArrayList<SongDetails> songs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("Data1");

    for(SongDetails songDetails : songs) {
        Log.i("", songDetails.getSong());
    }
}
```

Your SongDetails class should look like this:

**SongDetails:**

```
public class SongDetails implements Parcelable {
    Bitmap icon;
    String song;
    String Artist;
    String Album;
    String Path;
    int icLauncher;

    public SongDetails() {
    }

    public SongDetails(Parcel in) {
        String[] data = new String[1];
        in.readStringArray(data);
        this.song = data[0];
    }

    public String getSong() {
        return song;
    }

    public void setSong(String song) {
        this.song = song;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return Artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String Artist) {
        this.Artist = Artist;
    }

    public Bitmap getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.icon = bitmap;
    }

    public String getPath2() {
        return Path;
    }

    public void setPath2(String Path) {
        this.Path = Path;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {
        return Album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String Album) {
        this.Album = Album;
    }

    public void setIcon(int icLauncher) {
        this.icLauncher = icLauncher;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeStringArray(new String[] { this.song });
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public SongDetails createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new SongDetails(in);
        }

        public SongDetails[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SongDetails[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: should the receiving and the class which is passing still implement serializable or parceleable

Comment: when i write this line

 intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Data1", list);

it says cast argument of list to ArrayList<?Extends Parceable>

Comment: is your class SongDetails defined as following: public class SongDetails implements Parcelable { … } ?

Comment: i casted that and it crashed again

Comment: you don't have to cast anything. i uploaded my example again (with multiple songs), take a look and ask if you don't get parts of it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4iqbwf5fv9fq413/Test.zip

Comment: did you run it? if yes: did it print out song1 and song2 in the adb?

Comment: It did print out "song1" and "song2" into the logcat of eclipse. That's the corresponding code: for(SongDetails songDetails : songs) {
   Log.i("", songDetails.getSong());
  }

Comment: well i can't see anything in the log....so i edited the code so that it prints it in the textview.......and yes it displays it...

Comment: so, that should show you how you can pass along two songs to the next intent. did this solve your question?

Comment: yeah the app is not crashing anymore...thanx to you..i will have to edit it to use it for my own purpose

Comment: for(SongDetails songDetails : songs) {
   Log.i("", songDetails.getSong());
this code works fine...but when i use ...it doesn't work...so i am still stuck    

Log.i("", songs.get(0).getSong());

Comment: you probably better use ArrayList<SongDetails> songs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("Data1"); in your receiving class.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/challenge-saving-state-notserializableexception-error/8018/5 you should implement or extend some class from `Parcelable`. 
In my case I had a DialogFragment with an interface MyCallback extending Serializable. In `newInstance(MyCallback callback)` builder I used:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable(key, callback);
```

that led to an exception.
Then I rewrote MyCallback to extend `Parcelable` and also added some methods to a callback when invoked this DialogFragment. At least, it doesn't crash on Home button or screen off.

Also changed to:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putParcelable(key, callback);
```

Comment: could you share how you do "MyCallback to extend Parcelable"? 
also, did you tried a callback that deals with context, livedata?

Comment: @MahmoudMabrok, it's a good question. I forgot what had done. Probably passed data like `data class MyCallback(data: SomeClass, callback: (Context) -> Unit): Parcelable`. Here `data class SomeClass(...): Parcelable` and `callback` is not parcelable. Currently I don't use `LiveData`, only `StateFlow`, but don't use this solution at all. You are right, it would be better to use `setFragmentResultListener`, I suppose.

Comment: the issue here, that we need to do action/callback while dialog is opened.

Comment: @MahmoudMabrok, I think, you should ask a new question. If we cannot pass a method to `Dialog`, we can create a class (interface) with needed methods and pass it there. Then in `Dialog` create an instance of that class and make work.

Answer (score 0):

I know where the problem is in your case and that is about the **BitMap**
All you need to do is 
Decode your BitMap before sending into intent

```
Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.thumbsup);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        largeIcon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

And then send the following Object in intent

```
intent.putExtras("remindermessage",object);
```

and if not about the Bitmap then you should look for other things which might be taking more space and decode them before sending into intent

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a nested Delivery class inside the actual class Order (implements
Serializable) which was not serialized, once Delivery class also implemented Serializable, the exception is gone. I didn't have to implement parcelable at all. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

**To get the arraylist from another activity.**

```
      ArrayList<SongDetails> list = new ArrayList<SongDetails>();
              list=  getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("Data1");
```

**To pass the arraylist to another activity.**

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Data1", Songinfo);
```

**To split the array list:**

```
        for(SongDetails name: list)
        {
        String yoursong= name.song;
        }
```

Hope this will give you some solution.

Comment: .getStringArrayListExtra(
and here the code is to fetch string

Comment: no it didn't work....and how can it??Songinfo is not a string its an object of SongDetails ,a class that i have created

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava what is Songinfo? means how did u declare this?where did you declare?

Comment: final ArrayList<SongDetails> Songinfo = getSongsFromDirectory(f);

Comment: i have tried it already.....the code gets marked with red line and one of the auto correct option says"change type of Songinfo to ArrayList<String>